# Hide LineChart DataSet. Swift IOS

Tags: ios, swift, charts, hidden, invisible

How to set a line chart dataset as disabled on load

I am using the Charts frameworks (danielgindi/Charts).

I want to have a lineChartView that's including 3 different of Data which can use button to hidden or show them.

E.g. button1 had been tapped will show/invisible on the lineChartView but others 2 different of Data still showing.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var chartView: LineChartView!

    var limitSet1 : ChartLimitLine?
    var limitSet2 : ChartLimitLine?
    var limitSet3 : ChartLimitLine?
    var limitLineArray : [Double] = []

    func removeLimitLines() {
        switch (limitLineArray.count) {
        case 1: print("there was 1 limit line, need to remove this from chart view")
        chartView.rightAxis.removeLimitLine(limitSet1!)
        case 2: print("there was 2 limit line, need to remove this from chart view")
        chartView.rightAxis.removeLimitLine(limitSet1!)
        chartView.rightAxis.removeLimitLine(limitSet2!)
        case 3: print("there was 3 limit line, need to remove this from chart view")
        chartView.rightAxis.removeLimitLine(limitSet1!)
        chartView.rightAxis.removeLimitLine(limitSet2!)
        chartView.rightAxis.removeLimitLine(limitSet3!)
        default:
            break
        }
    }

    func setChart(xValues: [String], valuesLineChart: [[Double]], limitLines: [Double]) {
//        chartView.descriptionText = ""
        chartView.noDataText = "You need to provide data for the chart."

        print("valuesLineChart has \(valuesLineChart.count) lines")

        var dataSets : [LineChartDataSet] = [LineChartDataSet]()

        switch valuesLineChart.count {

        case 1 : print("1 within switch")

        var yVals1 : [ChartDataEntry] = [ChartDataEntry]()
        for i in 0..<xValues.count {
            yVals1.append(ChartDataEntry(x: valuesLineChart[0][i], y: Double(i)))
        }

        let set1 = LineChartDataSet(entries: yVals1, label: nil)
        dataSets.append(set1)

        //limit lines
        limitSet1 = ChartLimitLine(limit: limitLines[0], label: "switch1, limit1")
        chartView.rightAxis.addLimitLine(limitSet1!)

        case 2 :print("2 within switch")

        var yVals1 : [ChartDataEntry] = [ChartDataEntry]()
        for i in 0..<xValues.count {
            yVals1.append(ChartDataEntry(x: valuesLineChart[0][i], y: Double(i)))
        }

        var yVals2 : [ChartDataEntry] = [ChartDataEntry]()
        for i in 0..<xValues.count {
            yVals2.append(ChartDataEntry(x: valuesLineChart[1][i], y: Double(i)))
        }

        let set1 = LineChartDataSet(entries: yVals1, label: nil)
        let set2 = LineChartDataSet(entries: yVals2, label: nil)

        dataSets.append(set1)
        dataSets.append(set2)

        //limit lines
        limitSet1 = ChartLimitLine(limit: limitLines[0], label: "")
        limitSet2 = ChartLimitLine(limit: limitLines[1], label: "")

        chartView.rightAxis.addLimitLine(limitSet1!)
        chartView.rightAxis.addLimitLine(limitSet2!)


        case 3 :print("3 within switch")

        var yVals1 : [ChartDataEntry] = [ChartDataEntry]()
        for i in 0..<xValues.count {
            yVals1.append(ChartDataEntry(x: valuesLineChart[0][i], y: Double(i)))
        }

        var yVals2 : [ChartDataEntry] = [ChartDataEntry]()
        for i in 0..<xValues.count {
            yVals2.append(ChartDataEntry(x: valuesLineChart[1][i], y: Double(i)))
        }

        var yVals3 : [ChartDataEntry] = [ChartDataEntry]()
        for i in 0..<xValues.count {
            yVals3.append(ChartDataEntry(x: valuesLineChart[2][i], y: Double(i)))
        }

        let set1 = LineChartDataSet(entries: yVals1, label: nil)
        let set2 = LineChartDataSet(entries: yVals2, label: nil)
        let set3 = LineChartDataSet(entries: yVals3, label: nil)

        dataSets.append(set1)
        dataSets.append(set2)
        dataSets.append(set3)

        //limit lines
        limitSet1 = ChartLimitLine(limit: limitLines[0], label: "")
        limitSet2 = ChartLimitLine(limit: limitLines[1], label: "")
        limitSet3 = ChartLimitLine(limit: limitLines[2], label: "")

        chartView.rightAxis.addLimitLine(limitSet1!)
        chartView.rightAxis.addLimitLine(limitSet2!)
        chartView.rightAxis.addLimitLine(limitSet3!)
        default:
            break
        }
       let chartData = LineChartData( dataSets: dataSets)
        chartView.data = chartData
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

One trick is using multiple dataSets to implement this. When you click your button, just refresh the dataSets.

```
var dataSetArray = []
switch btn {
case btn1:
    btn1.isSelected = !btn1.isSelected
    if btn1.isSelected {
        dataSetArray.append(1)
    }
case btn2:
    btn2.isSelected = !btn2.isSelected
    if btn2.isSelected {
        dataSetArray.append(2)
    }
case btn3:
    btn3.isSelected = !btn3.isSelected
    if btn3.isSelected {
        dataSetArray.append(3)
    }
}

//Add the dataSet
....
chartView.data = xxx
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your reply..

Sorry for that.
I not really understand what you said.
Can you say it more clearly ? Thank you

Comment: hi freecss, I saw your code. It seems nothing wrong with it. Previously I thought you want to hide any value in your data set. So what's the problem now?

Comment: Thank you Tony.
E.g. within case1, 1 line is shown, case 2, 2 lines are shown etc.. & this works as expected.
but i what i wan is case 1 tapped, "1" line shown or hide, but data2 and data 3 still showing or all no show, case 2 tapped, "2" line shown or hide, but data1 and data3 still showing or all no show, case 3 tapped, "3" line shown or hide, but data1 and data2 still showing or all no show

Comment: I got it. If you want to show/hide your line, just add/remove the dataSet as an optional. When you reset the chart, like mychartView.data = xxData, all lines will be removed and redraw. See my answer above

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply..
Really appreciate for it..

Sorry for confuse What i exactly want is  when i tapped button 1 then show dataset1, when i tap both its show all dataset..

It's mean tapped button the dataset hidden and show.

Comment: I think you can just store the index of button selected. Then add the dataSet of the index to the array, reload it.

Comment: Thank you always .It’s that possible to make 3kinds of choices by using button ? Eg. button 1 tapped show/hide. If shown then i click the button 2 , button2 will show with dataset1 and dataset2 . If clicked 1 more time then only show dataset1 and if i clicked button 3, will show dataset3 and dataset1 .. etc how do i possible to do that

Comment: hi freecss, see my answer above, I think the problem is your strategy that add/remove the dataset.

Comment: Thank you tony, sorry i just start programming at this month. Can you tell me more clearly ?